# Why do I always have to go through password recovery to log in?

Tags: support, login

Every time I want to log into Stack Overflow I type in my credentials and then get a "Wrong email or password" pop up. Then I click the "forgot password" link type in my email (the same I used before) and then in the recovery mail I click the link, set the password (always the same, copy-paste it from my notepad) and then I am logged in.

This is the case for any device I use **every** time; I always use the same email and password combination.

So why is the regular login form apparently not working for my account?

Comment: You say you copy and paste it from notepad, is it possible that you are copying and pasting a return character that you are not entering when you are logging in?

Comment: Nope, I dont think so, I always copy-paste by now, in order to make sure to eliminate that particular source of error, I copy-paste when I try to log in and I copy-paste when I reset the password. So I don't think it is that

Comment: Have you tried going ahead and changing your password instead of reusing the old one?

Comment: I have had this problem for a while and only rather recently started reusing the same password. In "the beginning" I just used a new password, only when I realized that I would repeatedly go through this process I started the copy-pasting

Comment: I know this isn't a security discussion or anything, but I would like to mention using a password manager like KeePass or something is more secure than storing your passwords as plaintext in notepad, and those password managers make it so you never worry about copying a return character because it's not a formatted document.